# Exporting from Mongoose to CSV with Mixed Objects

Tags: json, node.js, csv, object, mongoose

I went over tens of libraries and functions. I probably lack some knowledge in the field, cuz I can't figure out what adjustments need to be done in order to modify the existed libraries, or at least define the properties properly to make it work.

I have the following structure in my DB:

```
var keywordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   keyword: { type: String, lowercase: true },
   addedToDB: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   updates: [{ 
      date: {type: Date, default: new Date},
      traffic: Number,
      difficulty: Number,
      competition: Number,
      updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
   }]
});
```

Now, I want to have the ability to export all words to a CSV file with the following headers:

```
Keyword, Traffic, Difficulty, Competition, Date
```

Where each row is a different keyword AND the traffic, difficulty, competition, and date, are the most recent data for this word in the DB( the most recent data is the index in the "updates" array that his "date" value is the most recent one).

I can handle the finding the most recent one, I just couldn't find a good way to export it.

Help please?

If something is unclear, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) module ?

e.g :

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fields = ['keyword', 'traffic', 'difficulty','competition','date'];
var fieldNames = ['Keyword', 'Traffic', 'Difficulty', 'Competition', 'Date'];

var myData = // YOUR DATA
try {
  var result = json2csv({ data: myData, fields: fields,fieldNames:fieldNames });
  fs.writeFile('word-ranker.csv', result, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

**NOTE** : Make sure **myData** should have direct fields.

Hope this help You.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes I tried this library as well, but notice that as you mentioned I need myData to have direct fields, and my structure is not build this way... any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to work something out. Just one more thing, how can I configure it to download the file instead of saving it?

Comment: You can set header like below and send the file:```res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/force-download','Content-disposition':`attachment; filename=myData.csv`});
            res.end(myData);```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried that already, but it gives me the data before I organized it.

Comment: res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=verifiedKeywords_'+getTodayDate()+'.csv'
    });

    
    Keyword.find().lean().exec(function (err, keywords) {
        var newStruct = customizeJsonResult(keywords);
        
        return res.end(JSON.stringify(newStruct));
    });

Comment: just ot be more specific, the downloaded file is basically the new JSON data spread over the first row as it was a long string (including brackets and everything). It is not separated to columns etc.

Comment: Remove ```JSON.stringify(newStruct)``` and make it to ```res.end(newStruct)```. This should work.